# Jquery If condition display message based on submission or failure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Im learning Jquery and AJAX on my own through online tutorials and by posting on SO when I gets stuck, so please keep in mind I am a novice should you be so kind to answer my question.

I have a form inside a modalbox. Ajax prevents it from closing/reloading and a message gets displayed after submission as you can see in image below:

[image]

**My problem**

Both the success and failure messages gets displayed. I would like to change this so that 1) Success message gets displayed on successfull submission or 2) failure message gets displayed on failed submission:

**My Form**

```
 <div id="inline3" style="width:400px;display: none;">
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <form name="message-form" action="" id="contact-form" method"post">
        Message<br /> <input type="text" name="msg" value="" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Contact Us" name="contact" class="buttono" />
        </form>
        <div class="form-feedback" style="display:none">
        Thank You We will Get Back to you 
        </div>
         <div class="form-feedback" style="display:none">
        Ooops....Something Went Wrong
        </div>
       <div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $form = $(this);

    $.post(document.location.url, $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        $feedback = $("<div>").html(data).find(".form-feedback").hide();
        $form.prepend($feedback)[0].reset();
        $feedback.fadeIn(1500)
    })

    });
})
```

If anyone can give me a bit of help or advise here it will be greatyly appreciated.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would do is change the backend so that instead of returning html it return json containing only the information you need (like whether the submission was a success or failure and any other messages, etc.).

Then the easiest fix that comes to my mind is to give each of your two feedback message divs unique id's:

```
<div id="form-feedback-success" class="form-feedback" style="display:none">
Thank You We will Get Back to you 
</div>
 <div id="form-feedback-error" class="form-feedback" style="display:none">
Ooops....Something Went Wrong
</div>
```

Keep the class names so that you can use css to style the two in a similar manner.

Then in your javascript check for a success or failure flag. Based on the flag display one or the other div based on the id:

```
$.post(document.location.url, $(this).serialize(), function(data){
    if(data.success) {
        $('#form-feedback-success').fadeIn(1500);
    }
    else {
        $('#form-feedback-error').fadeIn(1500);
    }
});
```

You may need to make some tweeks(like deserialize the response from json to an object), but that is the gist of it.

Comment: you are missing a key problem. He is posting back to the current page! The return is both HTML and much more than required.